# Amazon DynamoDB - disjunction ( OR ) in Scan/Query expression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am moving part of my application from MySQL to DynamoDB.
One of the queries I am trying to rewrite looks like that ( in SQL ):

```
select .... from ... where value is null or value = false;
```

I wonder, how can I rewrite disjunction ( this OR clause ) in DynamoDB?
For the moment I just check if the value is false:

```
scanExpression.addFilterCondition("value", new Condition().
    withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ).
    withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(BOOLEAN_FALSE)));
```

Any help/advice would be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: DynamoDB tables wont accept null values.

Comment: @HarshalBulsara - you can pretty much treat the non-existence of an attribute as null

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Conditional Operator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-ConditionalOperator) as part of your scan to either `AND` or `OR` multiple conditions together. Simply use the [ScanRequest.setConditionalOperator API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/ScanRequest.html#setConditionalOperator(java.lang.String)) and add multiple conditions.

As a note, you wouidn't actually store `NULL` as an item's attribute; instead, treat the absence of an attribute as `NULL`.